# _psycopg of psycopg2 not found

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, importerror

So I have been using `psycopg2` for a while now, but it is only now that I have encountered this error upon running our script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "engine/LinkOracleEngine.py", line 8, in <module>
    from util.DoSQL import DoSQL
  File "/home/zero/Documents/Thesis/Source Code/engine/util/DoSQL.py", line 4, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: No module named _psycopg
```

Why is that? From my previous uses, there was no problem in importing `psycopg2`, but now it has. I updated it and there seems no changes, I even installed another `psycopg2` through `pip3` but it is still the same.

I even tried importing `sys` in the python console, then appended the library where it was located (`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/`) to the `sys.path`, but still gets the same `ImportError: No module named _psycopg`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/')
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: No module named _psycopg
>>> sys.path
['', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/zero/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/']
>>>
```

Last time I remembered doing was setting up a cluster between my laptop and PC with `mpich` and `mpich4py`, but that doesn't seem to directly affect my `psycopg2` right? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: looks like you have multiple installs of python, one for the system, second from anaconda - install your postgres module for the anacona's python (using pip that is connected to that distribution or conda/miniconda )